# Changing SSRS expression to sum MTD values

Tags: reporting-services

I have written a formula to give me sums based on MTD -- 1 month ago, 2 months ago, 3 months ago, etc by changing the `.addmonths()` value to -1,-2,-3, etc.

should be very simple but how to I change my formula to reflect current MTD?? so 5/1-5/6?

I have already tried changing the `.addmonths()` to `.addmonths(0)`, `.addmonths()`, and completely removing the `.addmonths()` code.

```
=sum(IIf(Year(Fields!AppDateActualDate.Value) = 
     Year(DateAdd("d",-1, Now).AddMonths(0)) And 
     Month(Fields!AppDateActualDate.Value) = Month(DateAdd("d",-1, Now).AddMonths(0)) AND 
     DatePart("d", Fields!AppDateActualDate.Value) <=day(DateAdd("d",-1, Now).AddMonths(0)), 
     Fields!Total_Apps.Value, Nothing), )
```

Comment: Except for the extra comma at the end, the expression seems to be working. What's the issue?

Comment: Thanks, I just realized I had a filter on my table that was not allowing me to see the current month data! I was staring at this for so long so confused! Woops! Thank you again